# How can I make an image file appear by default in my Upload component? (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am attempting to create an image file uploader with React that displays a preview of the file that is selected by the user. I was able to make it so that when a user selects an image, that image is previewed and is displayed correctly. However, I want a default image that I have in my '/images/user-solid.jpeg' path to appear by default, and for it to be replaced by whatever image the user selects. How can I accomplish this? Any information would be appreciated, thank you! Here is a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-mountain-ynp569?file=/src/App.js

Upload.jsx:

```html
import '../../components/pages/styles/Uploads.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import authHeader from '../../services/auth-header';

function Uploads() {
    const {user: currentUser} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const [file, setFile] = useState();
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  
    const imageSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        const result = await axios.post(
            API_URL + '/image/upload',
            formData,
            {
                headers: {...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
            }
        );
        console.log(result.data);
    };

    return (
        <div className='page'>
            <div className='upload-card'>
                {file && (
                    <div id='preview'>
                        <img
                            src={URL.createObjectURL(file)}
                            id='image'
                            alt='Thumbnail'
                            className='user-post'
                        />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
            <div className='upload-container'>
                <div className='post-form-container'>
                    <p id='upload-form-label'>
                        Hello, {currentUser.username} feel free to post an image!
                    </p>
                    <form
                        onSubmit={profileImageSubmit}
                        // onSubmit={'return Validate(this);'}
                        className='upload-form'
                    >
                        <div className='panel'>
                            <div className='button_outer'>
                                <div className='btn_upload'>
                                    <input
                                        filename={file}
                                        onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                                        type='file'
                                        accept='image/*'
                                        id='image-selection-btn'
                                        Upload
                                        Image
                                    ></input>
                                    Choose your Art
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type='submit' id='post-upload-btn'>
                            Upload Image
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Uploads;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy take a look at this code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {} from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);

  const onAddImage = (file) => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
    setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
  };

  return (
    <div className="page">
      <div className="upload-card">
        <div id="preview">
          <img
            src={preview || require("./assets/user-solid.jpeg")}
            id="image"
            alt="Thumbnail"
            className="user-post"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="upload-container">
        <div className="post-form-container">
          <p id="upload-form-label">Hello, feel free to post an image!</p>
          <form
            // onSubmit={'return Validate(this);'}
            className="upload-form"
          >
            <div className="panel">
              <div className="button_outer">
                <div className="btn_upload">
                  <input
                    filename={file}
                    onChange={(e) => onAddImage(e.target.files[0])}
                    type="file"
                    accept="image/*"
                    id="image-selection-btn"
                  ></input>
                  Choose your Art
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="post-upload-btn">
              Upload Image
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-murdock-306b17?file=/src/App.js

Comment: For some reason it is not loading, and am getting some errors in the console. react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `img`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: img="true" or img={value.toString()}.

Comment: any idea what I need to do?

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Comment: unfortunately still receiving the same error :( im not sure what is going on

Comment: Ill keep looking.

Comment: I added a code sandbox link in my updated question, in case that helps

Comment: The sanbox doesnt contain the code for me

Comment: I apologize, im trying to make it public. Does it work now?

Comment: Look at my updated answer.

Comment: unfortunately not working, is there any way you could try seeing if you can copy my set up that is on the sandbox and see if you could get it working on there?

Comment: I got that working on sandbox lol

Comment: Sandbox link in answer.